# Aug 2019 - Kafka Consumer Lag programmatically

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-python

Is there any way we can programmatically find lag in the Kafka Consumer.
I don't want external Kafka Manager tools to install and check on dashboard.

We can list all the consumer group and check for lag for each group.

Currently we do have command to check the lag and it requires the relative path where the Kafka resides.

Spring-Kafka, kafka-python, Kafka Admin client or using JMX - is there any way we can code and find out the lag.

We were careless and didn't monitor the process, the consumer was in zombie state and the lag went to 50,000 which resulted in lot of chaos.

Only when the issue arises we think of these cases as we were monitoring the script but didn't knew it will be result in zombie process.

Any thoughts are extremely welcomed!!

Answer (score 3):

you can get this using kafka-python, run this on each broker or loop through list of brokers, it will give all topic partitions consumer lag.

```
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = '{}'.format(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
client = BrokerConnection(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, 9092, socket.AF_INET)
client.connect_blocking()
list_groups_request = ListGroupsRequest_v1()
future = client.send(list_groups_request)
while not future.is_done:
    for resp, f in client.recv():
      f.success(resp)
for group in future.value.groups:
    if group[1] == 'consumer':
      #print(group[0])
      list_mebers_in_groups = DescribeGroupsRequest_v1(groups=[(group[0])])
      future = client.send(list_mebers_in_groups)
      while not future.is_done:
        for resp, f in client.recv():
          #print resp
          f.success(resp)
          (error_code, group_id, state, protocol_type, protocol, members) = future.value.groups[0]
          if len(members) !=0:
            for member in members:
              (member_id, client_id, client_host, member_metadata, member_assignment) = member
              member_topics_assignment = []
              for (topic, partitions) in MemberAssignment.decode(member_assignment).assignment:
                member_topics_assignment.append(topic)

              for topic in member_topics_assignment:
                consumer = KafkaConsumer(
                          bootstrap_servers=BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
                          group_id=group[0],
                          enable_auto_commit=False
                          )
                consumer.topics()

                for p in consumer.partitions_for_topic(topic):
                  tp = TopicPartition(topic, p)
                  consumer.assign([tp])
                  committed = consumer.committed(tp)
                  consumer.seek_to_end(tp)
                  last_offset = consumer.position(tp)
                  if last_offset != None and committed != None:
                    lag = last_offset - committed
                    print "group: {} topic:{} partition: {} lag: {}".format(group[0], topic, p, lag)

                consumer.close(autocommit=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. We can get consumer lag in kafka-python. Not sure if this is best way to do it. But this works.

Currently we are giving our consumer manually, you also get consumers from kafka-python, but it gives only the list of active consumers. So if one of your consumers is down. It may not show up in the list.

First establish client connection

```
from kafka import BrokerConnection
from kafka.protocol.commit import *
import socket

#This takes in only one broker at a time. So to use multiple brokers loop through each one by giving broker ip and port.

def establish_broker_connection(server, port, group):
    '''
    Client Connection to each broker for getting consumer offset info
    '''
    bc = BrokerConnection(server, port, socket.AF_INET)
    bc.connect_blocking()
    fetch_offset_request = OffsetFetchRequest_v3(group, None)
    future = bc.send(fetch_offset_request)
```

Next we need to get the current offset for each topic the consumer is subscribed to. Pass the above future and bc here.

```
from kafka import SimpleClient
from kafka.protocol.offset import OffsetRequest, OffsetResetStrategy
from kafka.common import OffsetRequestPayload

def _get_client_connection():
    '''
    Client Connection to the cluster for getting topic info
    '''
    # Give comma seperated info of kafka broker "broker1:port1, broker2:port2'
    client = SimpleClient(BOOTSTRAP_SEREVRS)
    return client

def get_latest_offset_for_topic(self, topic):
    '''
    To get latest offset for a topic
    '''
    partitions = self.client.topic_partitions[topic]
    offset_requests = [OffsetRequestPayload(topic, p, -1, 1) for p in partitions.keys()]
    client = _get_client_connection()
    offsets_responses = client.send_offset_request(offset_requests)
    latest_offset = offsets_responses[0].offsets[0]
    return latest_offset # Gives latest offset for topic

def get_current_offset_for_consumer_group(future, bc):
    '''
    Get current offset info for a consumer group
    '''
    while not future.is_done:
        for resp, f in bc.recv():
            f.success(resp)

    # future.value.topics -- This will give all the topics in the form of a list.
    for topic in self.future.value.topics:
        latest_offset = self.get_latest_offset_for_topic(topic[0])
        for partition in topic[1]:
            offset_difference = latest_offset - partition[1]
```

offset_difference gives the difference between the last offset produced in the topic and the last offset (or message) consumed by your consumer.

If you are not getting current offset for a consumer for a topic then it means your consumer is probably down.

So you can raise alerts or send mail if the offset difference is above a threshold you want or if you get empty offsets for your consumer.

Comment: In the current version the `SimpleClient` is `DEPRECATED`
https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.1/simple.html

Answer (score 1):

The java client exposes the lag for its consumers over JMX; in this example we have 5 partitions...

[image]

Spring Boot can publish these to micrometer.

Comment: Hi Gary would be great if you show this in your Kafka Spring talks/videos!!

Comment: This is not really anything to do with Spring; the MBeans are exported by the `kafka-clients`. Spring Boot just has hooks to read these MBeans and publish them to micrometer.

Comment: But what happen to python consumer then my jconsole is not showing kafka.consumer, only in case of my Spring kafka consumers it is showing...Am i missing something?

Comment: No; the java client will only export MBeans for its own consumers.

Comment: then what we can do for those consumer, i have seen your answer of calling the consumer group describe command in Java program and loading the lag value...But there is no other way we can achieve it???

Comment: Not that I am aware of; the scala class that the CLI runs doesn't have an API to get the information.

Comment: But this will work only on the consumer. Not on Kafka Broker.

Comment: Because this will work only on the `Consumer` side and a question asks about a solution that can perform as `Kafka Manager` which works as a `Kafka Broker` monitoring not `Consumer`. On `Consumer`, there is hundreds of way to get this metric.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing code in scala but use only native java API from `KafkaConsumer` and `KafkaProducer`.

You need only know the name of Consumer Group and Topics.
it's possible to avoid pre-defined topic, but then you will get Lag only for Consumer Group which exist and which state is `stable` not rebalance, this can be a problem for alerting. 
So all that you really need to know and use are:

1. `KafkaConsumer.commited` - return latest committed offset for `TopicPartition`
2. `KafkaConsumer.assign` - do not use subscribe, because it causes to CG rebalance. You definitely do not want that your monitoring process to influence on the subject of monitoring.
3. `kafkaConsumer.endOffsets` - return latest produced offset
4. `Consumer Group Lag` - is a difference between the latest committed and latest produced

```
import java.util.{Properties, UUID}

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.{StringDeserializer, StringSerializer}

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.util.Try

case class TopicPartitionInfo(topic: String, partition: Long, currentPosition: Long, endOffset: Long) {
  val lag: Long = endOffset - currentPosition

  override def toString: String = s"topic=$topic,partition=$partition,currentPosition=$currentPosition,endOffset=$endOffset,lag=$lag"
}

case class ConsumerGroupInfo(consumerGroup: String, topicPartitionInfo: List[TopicPartitionInfo]) {
  override def toString: String = s"ConsumerGroup=$consumerGroup:\n${topicPartitionInfo.mkString("\n")}"
}

object ConsumerLag {

  def consumerGroupInfo(bootStrapServers: String, consumerGroup: String, topics: List[String]) = {
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", bootStrapServers)
    properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
    properties.put("group.id", consumerGroup)
    properties.put("key.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])
    properties.put("value.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])
    properties.put("key.serializer", classOf[StringSerializer])
    properties.put("value.serializer", classOf[StringSerializer])
    properties.put("client.id", UUID.randomUUID().toString)

    val kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](properties)
    val kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](properties)
    val assignment = topics
      .map(topic => kafkaProducer.partitionsFor(topic).asScala)
      .flatMap(partitions => partitions.map(p => new TopicPartition(p.topic, p.partition)))
      .asJava
    kafkaConsumer.assign(assignment)

    ConsumerGroupInfo(consumerGroup,
      kafkaConsumer.endOffsets(assignment).asScala
        .map { case (tp, latestOffset) =>
          TopicPartitionInfo(tp.topic,
            tp.partition,
            Try(kafkaConsumer.committed(tp)).map(_.offset).getOrElse(0), // TODO Warn if Null, Null mean Consumer Group not exist
            latestOffset)
        }
        .toList
    )

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(
      consumerGroupInfo(
        bootStrapServers = "kafka-prod:9092",
        consumerGroup = "not-exist",
        topics = List("events", "anotherevents")
      )
    )

    println(
      consumerGroupInfo(
        bootStrapServers = "kafka:9092",
        consumerGroup = "consumerGroup1",
        topics = List("events", "anotehr events")
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi-I have written a python code which will execute Kafka commands(from the Kafka directory) and will get the consumer group, then the next piece of code is to traverse each consumer group and execute describe command for each group using python and get the Lag column and print it against topic. [DRAWBACK-Code needs to be native to Kafka Directory and need to execute shell command to get details!]

Comment: @ArpanSharma There is a problem with `kafka-consumer-group.sh`.
This command return result only for `stable` consumer group.
In case Consumer Group in `rebalance` or all instances are down, the command will return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is looking for consumer lag in confluent cloud here is simple script

```
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "<>.aws.confluent.cloud"
CCLOUD_API_KEY = "{{ ccloud_apikey }}"
CCLOUD_API_SECRET = "{{ ccloud_apisecret }}"
ENVIRONMENT = "dev"
CLUSTERID = "dev"
CACERT = "/usr/local/lib/python{{ python3_version }}/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem"

def main():

  client = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers=BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
                            ssl_cafile=CACERT,
                            security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
                            sasl_mechanism='PLAIN',
                            sasl_plain_username=CCLOUD_API_KEY,
                            sasl_plain_password=CCLOUD_API_SECRET)

  for group in client.list_consumer_groups():
    if group[1] == 'consumer':
      consumer = KafkaConsumer(
                                   bootstrap_servers=BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
                                   ssl_cafile=CACERT,
                                   group_id=group[0],
                                   enable_auto_commit=False,
                                   api_version=(0,10),
                                   security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
                                   sasl_mechanism='PLAIN',
                                   sasl_plain_username=CCLOUD_API_KEY,
                                   sasl_plain_password=CCLOUD_API_SECRET
                                 )
      list_members_in_groups =  client.list_consumer_group_offsets(group[0])
      for (topic,partition) in list_members_in_groups:

        
        consumer.topics()

        tp = TopicPartition(topic, partition)
        consumer.assign([tp])
        committed = consumer.committed(tp)
        consumer.seek_to_end(tp)
        last_offset = consumer.position(tp)
        if last_offset != None and committed != None:
          lag = last_offset - committed
          print("group: {} topic:{} partition: {} lag: {}".format(group[0], topic, partition, lag))
      consumer.close(autocommit=False)
```