# How to find the consumer message lag in kafka using python?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I wanted to notify another person with a mail if there is a lag in the message in kafka consumer.

How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aug 2019 - Kafka Consumer Lag programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57302244/aug-2019-kafka-consumer-lag-programmatically)

Comment: @HenryWoody  could you please give me a more simpler way if der is any , to find the message lag using offsets in kafka using python